# FW400 HDD not recognized at all

Tags: macos, hard-drive, firewire

I have an external hard drive in an enclosure that plugs into the firewire port of a Mac Pro, and it is not recognized. I connect the device to the firewire port, and this is what it shows:

[image]
Any ideas on how to make the drive be recognized? Disk Utility does not see it, and neither does diskutil on terminal. Running Lion on a MacPro 4,1.

**Added**: I just noticed the power went out, so the drive might have shut down improperly. Is there a software to correct the drive again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, will the FireWire port work with another external hard drive with FireWire? This will rule out if the port has failed or not. IF you have another Mac nearby but not another external drive, another way to test this would be to see if the drive will mount on another Mac.

Second, can you dismantle the external enclosure and move the bare hard drive to another external enclosure, and see if that works? This will rule out whether the interface hardware in the external enclosure has failed.

If you don't have the equipment to test this, take the system to a repair facility that does have the equipment and can test it for you.

If you are fortunate, the bare hard drive is OK and only the enclosure will need to be replaced.

Comment: I don't have any other firewire devices, but I did plug the drive into another Mac and had the same results. Also, added that the power went out, and drive probably shut down inappropriately.

Comment: Pulled the drive, and installed it. The drive works, so I have to figure out what is wrong with my housing. Thanks for the help.